# If unsigned types should not have negative values, why is it negative when I turn on all the bits?

Tags: c, limit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long x = 0;

    x = x ^ ~x;
    printf("%d\n", x);

    x = (unsigned long)pow(2, sizeof(x)*8);
    printf("%d\n", x);

    x = ULONG_MAX;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using CodeBlocks12.11, and MinGW 4.7.0-1 on Windows 7. And for some reason I am having trouble making my variable `x` acquire the largest possible decimal value representation. Why does this happen, I am sure that `x = ULONG_MAX` should work but it also results in `-1`, now surely that is not right! I tried compiling it outside of Code-Blocks as well.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Yes, as @Zoidberg says, the compiler's warning would have pointed out your mistake right away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to print unsigned variables with `u`. A long is prefixed with `l`, hence you need `lu` in this case.

```
printf("%lu\n", x);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be something terribly obvious!

Comment: @PascalCuoq Tnx made a typo.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `%lu`?

Comment: @Mysticial My compiler only complains with `long long` with which i have to use `llu`. For everything else `u` is fine on my system.

Comment: @Armin I didn't downvote, but that's not correct. It's possible for `unsigned long` to be larger than `unsigned`. It might not be on your system, but the standard allows it.

Comment: @Leonardo turn on compiler warnings and listen to them. Any modern compiler will complain when the format specifiers do not match the types. You must not use the wrong specifier since that will (and should) undoubtedly break sometime.

Comment: @Zoidberg Thanks for the advice, I am turning all warnings on while I am learning C.

Comment: @Mysticial - it's not uncommon either. e.g. all 64bit Intel Linux and OS X systems have a 64bit long and 32bit int.